# Automated email with attachment with Phantom.js

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts, xampp, phantomjs

I have a question regarding daily automated email that scrape the highcharts table from a website and send them with xampp server daily.

So in a php page i have a process to generate chart retrieved from the oracle database. then i need to take the screenshot of that chart and send them as an attachment into our clients daily.

so far I know phantom JS has to be run from command prompt. Please help on how to solve this automatically. is there any other solution to approach this? or does phantom.js is able to execute this automatically and save the screenshot as email attachment?

Comment: http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: i tried that but it needs to be executed from command prompt... what i need is the server automation